Why does my css property value not inherit when getting a current.ref computed style?
I have the following JSX
<Level>
  <p>hey</p>
  <Level>
    <p> more hey</p>
  </Level>
</Level>

Level is like this
const Level = ({ children, value}) => {
    const levelRef = useRef();
 
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const el = levelRef.current;
        const style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
        let currentLevel = style.getPropertyValue('--currentLevel');
        console.log(currentLevel)
        if (!currentLevel) {
            console.log("current level not found");
            currentLevel = 1
            el.style.setProperty('--currentLevel', currentLevel);
            return; 
        }
    });

    return (
        <div ref={levelRef}>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

What I want is for the first Level to have no current Level but the second one, which is a child of the first div, I want that to have the currentLevel that was set by the parent level.
But that is not happening. Instead currentLevel is empty and set both times - how do I get it to inherit the --currentLevel property in the descendant refs?

My guess is that the way React work is that it renders children before rendering the parents, so useLayoutEffect would be called on the deeper Level before the root Level.  Can you try something like adding a initialized state, setting it to true when useLayoutEffect is called and rendering children when initialized is true ({ initialized && children }) ?`

right, it does seem to be something like that. thanks
